# How to only pull example of a value when more than 50% of the results match

Tags: sql, oracle

| Code | Error | Warning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 0 |
| ABC | 0 | 0 |
| ABC | 0 | 0 |
| DEF | 1 | 0 |
| DEF | 0 | 0 |
| DEF | 1 | 0 |
| GHI | 1 | 0 |
| GHI | 0 | 1 |

I need to be able to pull one value indicating that more than 50% of the values listed have a "1" in either the "error" or "warning" columns.

In this example, I would need to get back something like this:

| Code |
| --- |
| DEF |
| GHI |

Since both "DEF" and "GHI" had more than 50% of their total rows with a "1" in either the "Error" or "Warning" column. "ABC" would not be included since it did not meet the criteria of 50%.

Comment: If you had four `JKL` rows with one row as an error and one different row as a warning would you expect that row to be output as 2-of-4 rows have either an error or a warning or not to be output as neither 50% of the rows are errors nor 50% of the rows are warnings.

Answer (score 1):

If the values of `error` and `warning` are always either `1` or `0` your query can simply be:

```
select code
from main
group by code
having avg(error) >= .5
      or avg(warning) >= .5;
```

See it working here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=02cdf03753da82fe2d3686523165ff09

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT code
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY code
HAVING AVG(GREATEST(Error, Warning)) >= 0.5;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Code, Error, Warning) AS
SELECT 'ABC', 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC', 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF', 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF', 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DEF', 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI', 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GHI', 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JKL', 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JKL', 0, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JKL', 0, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JKL', 0, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CODE |
> | --- |
> | DEF |
> | GHI |
> | JKL |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=13d75bec5599ed6891bd608f68b04626)*

Comment: this is very clever

Answer (score 0):

```
with main as(
select 'ABC' as code, 1 as error, 0 as warning from dual
union all
select 'ABC' as code, 0 as error, 0 as warning from dual
union all
select 'ABC' as code, 0 as error, 0 as warning from dual
union all
select 'DEF' as code, 1 as error, 0 as warning from dual
union all
select 'DEF' as code, 0 as error, 0 as warning from dual
union all
select 'DEF' as code, 1 as error, 0 as warning from dual
union all
select 'GHI' as code, 1 as error, 0 as warning from dual
union all
select 'GHI' as code, 0 as error, 1 as warning from dual)

select 
    x.*,
    case
        when (code_error/code_total + code_warning/code_total) > 1/2 then 'show'
        else 'hide'
    end as isVisible    
from(
select distinct code,
    (select count(1) from main where code = x.code and error = 1) as code_error,
    (select count(1) from main where code = x.code and warning = 1) as code_warning,
    (select count(1) from main where code = x.code) as code_total
from main x)x
```

Answer (score 0):

This example works for any tables on DB:

```
with table1 as 
(
    select 1 as id, 'ABC' as code, 1 as error, 0 as warning from dual
    union all
    select 2 as id, 'ABC' as code, 0 as error, 0 as warning from dual
    union all
    select 3 as id, 'ABC' as code, 0 as error, 0 as warning from dual
    union all
    select 4 as id, 'DEF' as code, 1 as error, 0 as warning from dual
    union all
    select 5 as id, 'DEF' as code, 0 as error, 0 as warning from dual
    union all
    select 6 as id, 'DEF' as code, 1 as error, 0 as warning from dual
    union all
    select 7 as id, 'GHI' as code, 1 as error, 0 as warning from dual
    union all
    select 8 as id, 'GHI' as code, 0 as error, 1 as warning from dual
)
select 
    mm.* 
from (
    select 
        t1.*, 
        count(1) over () as rowcount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            ORDER BY id
        ) as rnum 
    from table1 t1 
) mm 
where mm.rnum > (mm.rowcount/2)
```